# Why do some methods/properties require a certain sheet to be active while others do not?

Tags: vba, excel

Why do some of of the methods and properties I use in VBA require a certain sheet to be active while others do not?

The following example works no matter if wks is active or not:

```
wks.Range("A1").Value = 1
```

The following example only works if wks is active otherwise an error is thrown:

```
wks.Range("A1:A70").Insert
```

EDIT: I thought it had to do with the insert function but judging from Gary's students answer it did not. The exact code that triggered me to ask the question is:

```
'Cut range from source row
Dim lSourceRow As Long
Dim lSourceStartColumn As Long
Dim lSourceEndColumn As Long
lSourceRow = t.Row
lSourceStartColumn = loSource.Range.Column
lSourceEndColumn = loSource.Range.Column + loSource.ListColumns.Count - 1
wksSource.Range(wksSource.Cells(lSourceRow, lSourceStartColumn), wksSource.Cells(lSourceRow, lSourceEndColumn)).Cut

'Select target worksheet for insert method
wksTarget.Activate

'Insert range into target row
Dim lTargetRow As Long
Dim lTargetStartColumn As Long
Dim lTargetEndColumn As Long
lTargetRow = loTarget.DataBodyRange.Row + loTarget.ListRows.Count
lTargetStartColumn = loTarget.Range.Column
lTargetEndColumn = loTarget.Range.Column + loTarget.ListColumns.Count - 1
wksTarget.Range(Cells(lTargetRow, lTargetStartColumn), Cells(lTargetRow, lTargetEndColumn)).Insert
```

And now I understand why. It must be because I haven't prefaced Cells with the worksheet object. It should be:

```
wksTarget.Range(wksTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lTargetStartColumn), wksTarget.Cells(lTargetRow, lTargetEndColumn)).Insert
```

Conclution from this:

The more experienced guys reading this are welcome to close this thread since the problem was another than I had thought.

Otherwise, going back to the original question, I am curious: Do any VBA commands require a certain worksheet to be active or do I never have to use `worksheet.Select` in my code? I'm wondering because I know I have encountered this "problem" before. But maybe then as now I made a mistake in my code.

Comment: It probably has to do with it being a worksheet related function or not.

Comment: What error are yougetting?

Comment: Commands that really relate to a Window rather than a worksheet (such as `freezepanes` or `Split`) require the sheet of interest to be active otherwise it has no window you can use to manipulate it.

Comment: Interesting, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have some other un-related bug.  The following works without error in the absence of protection:

```
Sub dural()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Insert
End Sub
```